# the delay before data begins to move after it has been sent an instruction to do so

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

From [the Oxford's Learner's dictionary definition of latency](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/latency?q=Latency):

> latency:
> the delay *before data begins to move* **after it has been sent an instruction to do so**

Do "*before data begins to move*" and "**after it has been sent an instruction to do so**" modify "the delay" independently?

Comment: This is a poorly written definition. Where is is from?

Comment: @ColleenV Oxford Learner's Dictionary. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/latency?q=Latency

Comment: Allow me: The delay between the time the data moves and the time  it receives an instruction to move. Simpler is  better. But this is really an editing question (wolf) hiding in sheep's clothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latency is basically the time between asking for a data packet and when you receive it. I can see why you're having a hard time understanding "the delay before data begins to move after it has been sent an instruction to do so".

Neither the before clause nor the after clause modify "delay". They are describing a range of time. The sentence is saying that "latency" is the time between two events. The first event is when "it has been sent an instruction to move" and the second event is when the "data begins to move".

Also, we don't send data an instruction to move. It can't move itself. A client requests data and a server responds to that request. There are other forms of latency in computing, but I don't want to get too far [into the weeds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-the-weeds).